# I Am suffering 3 days because of this error somebody Help me to solve this error?

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin\java.exe
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your environmental variables aren´t correct, take a look at this tutorial, this may help you to fix it.

https://youtu.be/oorfevovPWw